# Which LINQ statement is efficient for searching record using entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Which of the following statements is efficient for searching record from database using Entity Framework.

```
 var user = db.User.Where(u => u.id == userid).FirstOrDefault();
 // or
 var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == userid);
```

Although both work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will both be evaluated to the same SQL.

Use SQL Profiler to see what SQL is created.

Comment: This is such a simple query that it won't matter how you write it, it'll be the same SQL